# org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

Tags: rest, rest-assured

I am trying to call rest service using restassured framework  - getting this exception.

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder mapException
>      WARNING: WebApplicationException cause:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1, type=class com.digicel.selfcare.service.services.beans.request.FacebookNewsFeedRequest, genericType=class com.digicel.selfcare.service.services.beans.request.FacebookNewsFeedRequest.
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:207)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:72)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1109)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:851)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:253)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
>       at   org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
>       at         org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInv

```
@Path("social/")
public class MyService{

@POST
@Path("facebook/feeds")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<FacebookNewsFeedResult>getFacebookNewsFeed(FacebookNewsFeedRequest request, @Context HttpServletRequest httpReq)
}
```

This my jUnit : using restassured

```
 @Test
 public void getFacebookNewsFeedTest() throws Exception
 {
  final String resource = "social/facebook/feeds";

  String jsonContent = "{\"feedId\": \"100\",\"pull\": \"true\"}";

  expect().spec(okResponse).with().headers(this.authorizedHeaders).content(ContentType.JSON).content(jsonContent).post(selfCareServiceTest.buildURLForResource(resource));
  }
```

Comment: I don't use rest assured but the Content-Type header is being sent as text/plain, so it would seem you are not correctly setting the header to `application/json`. It don't seem `content` is what you are looking for. Is there not a `contentType` method or maybe you can set the `Content-Type` header explicitly.

Comment: thank you @peesKiilet. I tried with header and it worked.

Comment: Now I have to find a way to do it successfully using Rest assured.